# How to get server to accept multiple sockets on same port

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, outputstream, printwriter

I want the ServerSocket to accept 2 Sockets connecting on the same port. However, it will not print out what is being read from the BufferedReader and the sockets after being connected are still null.

Here is the Serversocket code:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
try {
Socket con;
int socketCounter= 0;
Socket first, second;
while (socketCounter!= 2) {
        con = serverSocket.accept();
        String input;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        if ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(input);
            if (input.equals("first")) {
                first = con;
            } else if (input.equals("second")) {
                second = con;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        socketCounter++;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the "first"

```
try {
    first = new Socket(URL, PORT);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(first.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(first.getInputStream());
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(first.getOutputStream()));
pw.println("first");
pw.flush();
} catch(Excpetion e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Second is basically the same:

```
try {
    second = new Socket(URL, PORT);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(second.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(second.getInputStream());
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(second.getOutputStream()));
pw.println("second");
pw.flush();
} catch(Excpetion e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I would preferably want to do this single threaded, however, if not, it's fine. Can anyone help?

Comment: any particular reason you want it single-threaded?  That's going to make your life a whole lot more difficult

Comment: No reason. Only to make it a bit easier, however, it could make things harder.

Comment: This code *already* accepts multiple connections on a single port. The fact that it is single-threaded is the *problem:* the second client can only communicate when the first one is finished. You need to handle each accepted connection in a different thread.

Answer (score -1):

When you create a ServerSocket, you have to define the port that server socket it will use to listen the client requests. Everytime that ServerSocket receives a request, that request will be redirect to another port defined by the ServerSocket. Normally, we instanciate a new thread and associate to it the a client work.
Check this example:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html

Comment: I forgot to include that the serversocket was instantiated before the try-catch. I will update the post. Thank you for the link. In the example, each client does the same thing, however, "first" and "second" do different things. That is why I check the input.

Comment: @user2874945 so make them do different things.  Create two classes that extend `Thread`, one for first and one for second, and then when you get a connection, check your input, and run the corresponding thread.

Comment: This answer is rubbish. The accepted socket has the same local port as the listening socket. The example does not show otherwise.